# How to use sed or AWK to separate a string (NOT string in files)

Tags: shell, sed, awk

How can I separate `.sh` files into a list?

I have tried:

```
ls *.sh  | xargs sed 's/\n/ /g' > out.txt
```

The return of `ls *.sh` is a long string with '\n' in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use:

```
ls -1 *.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `ls` here: use `ls` when you want human eyes to see the nicely formatted output, not for when you want to parse filenames as data. Choose one of:

```
files=$(echo *.sh)

ary=( *.sh ); files="${ary[*]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
ls *.sh | xargs
```

will give you want you want: a line with all the .sh files in the current folder.